# How to access the properties in an object that uses = instead of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have an HTTP GET request to one of my resources and am logging out the payload.

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  console.log("event \n", event);
  const data = event.channelAttributes;
  console.log("data \n", data);
  callback(null);
};
```

Logs:

```
event 
 {
  channelAttributes: '{status=ACTIVE, long_lived=false, forwarding=true, serviceNumber=facebook_c8xxx, twilioNumber=messenger:xxx, from=messenger:xxx, channel_type=facebook, proxySession=xxxx}',
  body: 'This is a test request body'
}
data 
 {status=ACTIVE, long_lived=false, forwarding=true, serviceNumber=facebook_cxxxx, twilioNumber=messenger:xx, from=messenger:xx, channel_type=facebook, proxySession=xxx}
```

How am I supposed to access any of the values of the channelAttributes keys?

It looks like an object but the key/value pairs are using equal signs and they are separated with commas like an array.

Comment: Two options... 1) Ask the API maintainers to respond with actual JSON. 2) Parse the string into something usable

Comment: I guess I could do a find = and replace with : to manually convert it to an object. This is coming from Twilio using their Studio HTTP request widget so I think I'm doing something wrong. Gonna add twilio tag on this.

Comment: Hi James, something seems really off with what you are seeing. Can you provide more details on how you are using the Twilio Studio HTTP Request widget to call your Twilio Function? You can configure the widget to POST JSON, https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request. You can also use Studio liquid syntax to convert an object to JSON, via the to_json directive - `to_json - convert Liquid objects to valid JSON e.g {{ flow.data | to_json }} #=> {"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}`

Comment: Hi Alan, I've tried a few different request body input values on the widget and have run into the same issue.  It looks like I need to use the Studio liquid syntax as you suggested. I haven't used it before so I'll give it a shot.

Here was my last attempt:
```{"data": "{{trigger.message.ChannelAttributes}}"}```

Comment: Got it, thank you!  ```{{ trigger.message.ChannelAttributes  | to_json }}``` returns

```{
  bodySHA256: 'xxxxx',
  status: 'ACTIVE',
  long_lived: false,
  forwarding: true,
  serviceNumber: 'xxxx',
  twilioNumber: 'messenger:xxx',
  from: 'messenger:xxx',
  channel_type: 'facebook',
  proxySession: 'xxx'
}```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse the string using the following rules

1. Remove the first (`{`) and last (`}`) characters
2. Split the string on `', '`
3. Iterate the resulting array and split again on `=` to produce key/value pairs
4. Run that through [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get the final object

```js
const channelAttributes = '{status=ACTIVE, long_lived=false, forwarding=true, serviceNumber=facebook_c8vnqcce0znzkyzy9gtwx5mahchmfyrg, twilioNumber=messenger:114439596595920, from=messenger:2702403943127879, channel_type=facebook, proxySession=KC7c2293ba47c1fe5467a0efc8cdad1a41}'

const data = Object.fromEntries(
    channelAttributes.slice(1, -1).split(', ').map(kv => kv.split('='))
)
    
console.info(data)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Gonna check this after dinner and let you know how it goes.